# Detecting Mobile Bandwidth/Connection Type

Tags: javascript, mobile, video, streaming, bandwidth

I am developing a website targeted for ALL devices from the most powerful desktop all the way down to awful feature phones. The website will be heavy on serving video content. I want the site to fail gracefully should the user not have sufficient connection or technology to accept the video stream playback, as far as replacing the video with static images.

Is there a way of detecting the bandwidth of the connection to the server from the client? My video streaming service provides multi-bitrate streaming and I know that I can detect device type and capability using the likes of user-agents and Modernizr. I think it may be possible to measure bandwidth by measuring the time it takes for a client to download a series of files if the filesize is previously known.

Can anyone suggest the most efficient way of providing what I am trying to achieve? Is there anything that I can get from headers? Is there a framework or API I can use? Is there an alternative method without having to poll the server. The back end is built on Java and I am open to using any client side-technology.

Apologies for an open-ended question, but I have no idea on the best way to achieve this!

Comment: For me personally I prefer a "play" button over the video so *I* can choose if I want to play it (and if I'm a user with a slow/expensive connection, I just won't click it.

Answer (score 0):

You answered your own question. The best way (and correct me if I'm wrong) is to just test how fast the device gets a file/files of a certain size.